# Is there another meaning of 'heat-seeking missile'?

Tags: meaning

> — Well, Lindsay’s “M.O.” is to get her hooks into powerful, married men.
> — Look. She’s a *heat-seeking missile*. And Eddie has no heat. Your
> friend, Alex, does.
>
> [Law and Order](https://tvshowtranscripts.ourboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=421&t=21701)

FYI, Lindsay is a gold digger.

I googled 'heat-seeking missile' and [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Heat%20Seeking%20Missile&amp=true) says it's slang that describes male's genitals.
But I don't think that's not what the speaker wanted to say.

Is there another meaning of 'heat-seeking missile'?
Like a gold digger?
Or is it just figure of speech?

Comment: It means she goes straight for married men like a *heat-seeking missile* would target the heat of an aircraft.

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot!

Comment: @Lily In *figurative* terms, the entire passage is saying that Lindsay only goes after men who have passion. (Passion is considered to be hot.) No doubt, if she's really after money (it doesn't actually say that, but your supposition could be correct), then those men who are dispassionate won't be taken in by her act. As opposed to men who are passionate and let their emotions take over. (At least that's what the passage is saying.)

Comment: I heard it used by one of the characters in Underbelly to describe another character - a flamboyant showpony who attracted trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at "Urban Dictionary" and those are not official definitions at all. Those definitions are created by random people trying to be funny. Heat seeking missile is just what it says. It's a missile used in war, not male genitalia.

Answer (score 0):

The term, heat-seeking missile, is a term sometimes used idiomatically for a number of things: seeking out a target instinctively is one meaning; but the other has to do with sexual instinct--which doesn't actually require a man's mind to be in gear. That's the sense by which I first heard the term.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).